# To find the rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find rank of 3 by 3 matrix which is obtained by multiplying a non zero columm matrix A of size 3 by 1 and a non zero row matrix of size 1 by 3

I took simple example and found answer 1. But textbook states 0

Thanks for help

Comment: The textbook is wrong. The rank is obviously 1.